# Understanding the workflow of the messages in a generic server implementation in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, erlang, actor

The following code is from "Programming Erlang, 2nd Edition". It is an example of how to implement a generic server in Erlang.

```
-module(server1).
-export([start/2, rpc/2]).

start(Name, Mod) -> 
  register(Name, spawn(fun() -> loop(Name, Mod, Mod:init()) end)).

rpc(Name, Request) ->
  Name ! {self(), Request},
    receive
      {Name, Response} -> Response
    end.

loop(Name, Mod, State) ->
  receive
    {From, Request} ->
      {Response, State1} = Mod:handle(Request, State),
        From ! {Name, Response},
        loop(Name, Mod, State1)
  end.

-module(name_server).
-export([init/0, add/2, find/1, handle/2]).
-import(server1, [rpc/2]).

%% client routines
add(Name, Place) -> rpc(name_server, {add, Name, Place}).
find(Name)       -> rpc(name_server, {find, Name}).

%% callback routines
init() -> dict:new().
handle({add, Name, Place}, Dict) -> {ok, dict:store(Name, Place, Dict)};
handle({find, Name}, Dict)       -> {dict:find(Name, Dict), Dict}.


server1:start(name_server, name_server).
name_server:add(joe, "at home").
name_server:find(joe).
```

I tried so hard to understand the workflow of the messages. Would you please help me to understand the workflow of this server implementation during the executing of the functions: server1:start, name_server:add and name_server:find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is an introduction to the behavior concept used in Erlang. It illustrates how you can build a server in 2 parts:

The first part is the module server1 which contains only generic features that could be used by any server. Its role is to maintain available some
information (the State variable) and to be ready do answer some request. This is what the gen_server behavior does, with much more features.

The second part is the module name_server. This one describe what a particular sever does. It implements interfaces for the user of the server and internal functions (callback)  which describe what to do for each specific user request.

Lets follow the 3 shell commands (see diagram at the end):

**server1:start(name_server, name_server).** the user calls the start routine of the generic server, giving 2 informations (with the save values), the name of the server he wants to start, and the name of the module which contains the callbacks. with this the generic start routine

1/ calls back the init routine of name_server to get the server state `Mod:init()`, you can see that the generic part does not know which kind of information it will keep; the state is created by the name_server:init/0 routine, the first callback function. here it is an empty dictionary `dict:new()`.

2/ spawns a new process calling the generic server loop, with the 3 informations (server name, callback module and initial server state) `spawn(fun() -> loop(Name, Mod, Mod:init())`. The loop itself just starts and wait for a message of the form {*,*} in the receive block.

3/ registers the new process with the name name_server `register(Name, spawn(fun() -> loop(Name, Mod, Mod:init()) end))`.

4/ returns to the shell.

At this point, in parallel to the shell, there is a new living process named name_server running and waiting for a request. Note that generally this step is not done by the user, but by the application. It is why there is no interface to do that in the callback module, and that the start function is directly called in the generic server.

**name_server:add(joe, "at home").** The user adds an information in the server, calling the add function of the name_server . This interface is here to hide the mechanism to call the server, and it runs in the client process.

1/ The add function calls the rpc routine of the server with 2 parameters `rpc(name_server, {add, Name, Place})`: the callback module and the request itself `{add, Name, Place}`. the rpc routine is still executed in the client process,

2/ it builds a message for the server made of 2 information: the pid of the client process (here the shell) and the request itself then send it to the named server: `Name ! {self(), Request},`

3/ The client waits for a response. Remember that we left the server waiting for a message in the loop routine.

4/ The message sent matches the expected format `{From, Request}` of the server, so the server enters in the message processing. First it callback the name_server module with 2 parameters: the request and the current state `Mod:handle(Request, State)`. the intent is to have a generic server code, so it is not aware of what to do with the requests. In the name_server:handle/2 function, the right operation is done. Thanks to pattern matching, the clause `handle({add, Name, Place}, Dict) -> {ok, dict:store(Name, Place, Dict)};` is called and a new dictionary is created storing the key/value pair Name/Place (here joe/"at home"). the new dict is returned with the response in a tuple {ok,NewDict}.

5/ Now the generic server can build the answer and return it to the client `From ! {Name, Response},` en re-enter in the loop with the new state `loop(Name, Mod, State1)` and wait for the next request.

6/ The client who was waiting on the receive block get the message {Name, Response} and can then extract the Response and return it to the shell, here it is simply ok.

**name_server:find(joe).** The user wants to get an information from the server. The process is exactly the same as before, and it is the interest of the generic server. whatever the request is, it does the same job. When you will look into gen_server behavior, you will see that there are several kind of accesses to the sever such as call, cast, info... So if we look at the flow of this request:

1/ call rpc with callback module and request `rpc(name_server, {find, Name}).`

2/ send a message to the server with client pid and request

3/ wait for the answer

4/ the server receive the message and callback the name_server with the request `Mod:handle(Request, State),` it get the response from the handle `handle({find, Name}, Dict) -> {dict:find(Name, Dict), Dict}.` which returns the result of the dictionary search and the dictionary itself.

5/ the server build the answer and sent it to the client `From ! {Name, Response},` and re-enter in the loop with the same state, waiting for the next request.

6/ The client who was waiting on the receive block get the message {Name, Response} and can then extract the Response and return it to the shell, now it is the place where joe is: "at home".

the next picture shows the different message exchanges:

[image: kind of sequence diagram of the 3 steps described previously]

Comment: I appreciate every second you spent writing this answer! Thanks a lot.